# Seekng in audio tag and Scrolling the text

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to move my paragraph vertically along with the audio.
So far I tried it with  but each time I tried seeking the audio or jumping for  few seconds, my marquee is not in sync with my audio.

Is there any way I can try my paragraph scrolling  using this

[image: audio tag controls]

?

The scrolling should stop when the audio is pause,
should resume when the audio is playing again.

Comment: Could you add a jsfiddle or code snippet?

Comment: @www139 there. I've edited it.

Comment: `center` and `marquee` are both deprecated!

Comment: @www139 Thanks for the edit. But  I'm trying to get the whole paragraph move vertically like a marquee would do but it must sync with the way I tried to move the seeking controls of my audio tag. The seeking will act just like a scroll bar

Comment: I understand now :) Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 is all set up for this.

[See here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/track/basics/) for a basic guide. This shows how to use a `caption` `<track>` with the `<video>` element, but it works for `<audio>` as well.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/track) is a reference page.

Comment: Thanks but, I'm still new to HTML, this code seems to be working by only showing a sentence at a time. I'm trying to get the whole paragraph move vertically like a marquee would do but it must sync with the way I tried to move the seeking controls of my audio tag. The seeking will act just like a scroll bar :V